powershell outlook get meeting organizer from sent item
When I have been invited to a meeting and I Accept (or mark Tentative, or Decline), a sent item appears in olFolderSentMail, and shows up in the list generated by this powershell code:
$olFolderSentMail = 5
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$ns = $ol.GetNamespace('MAPI')
$Start = $targetDate.ToShortDateString() + " 00:00"
$End = $targetDate.AddDays(+1).ToShortDateString() + " 00:00"
$sentMail = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderSentMail)

$sentMail.Items | Where-Object { $_.ReceivedTime -ge "$Start" -and $_.ReceivedTime -lt "$End" } | ForEach-Object {
    $organizer = $_.MeetingOrganizer
    "{0,-20} {1,-20} {2,-20} {3:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {4}" -f $_.To, $organizer, $_.CC, $_.ReceivedTime, $_.Subject
} | Out-String -Width 1024

Output looks like this:
<spaces>2024-04-05 06:59:00 Tentative: meeting subject

Nothing appears in either "To" or "MeetingOrganizer". If I go look at my Outlook sent items folder, the organizer name is there. What am I doing wrong?
This is Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2403 Build 16.0.17425.20124) 64-bit.
Thanks for any help you can provide!
--
Thanks Dmitry Streblechenko for your answer! Here's what I did:
...
$Filter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '$Start' AND [ReceivedTime] < '$End'"

$sentMail.Items.Restrict($Filter) | ForEach-Object {
  $to = $_.To
  $appt = $_.getAssociatedAppointment($true)
  if ($appt -ne $null) {
    $to = $appt.Organizer
  }

  "{0,-20} {1,-20} {2:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {3}" -f $to, $_.CC, $_.ReceivedTime, $_.Subject
} | Out-String -Width 1024

Edit: sigh but it doesn't work for declines. Why?? To, Organizer, and recipients are all empty (even though Outlook sent items shows who it went to). Even better, I first accepted, then responded tentative, then declined a meeting. Organizer was present for the first two, but once I marked "Declined" all three (accept, tentative, decline) lost the organizer.

Where did you come up with the property "MeetingOrganizer"? My first guess is this is AI generated and it made up a property for you.

You caught me lol. Any idea what the right answer is here? I was hoping it was just the "To" field.

For a decline, you won't have an appointment. Do use MeetingItem.Recipients collection and read first Recipient.Name/Address

Firstly, don't ever loop through all items in an Outlook folder - use Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict.
Secondly, MeetingItem object does not expose MeetingOrganizer property. Ditto for the To property.
You can call MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment() method to get the corresponding AppointmentItem object (the call will be fairly expensive) and read the AppointmentItem.Organizer property or you can assume that the MeetingItem was sent to the meeting organizer, therefore the organizer will be the one and only recipient. Access the first recipient in the MeetingItem.Recipients collection and read the Recipient.Name/Address/etc. properties.

Thanks, this really helped! I'll update the question to show solution.
